# Jquery get attribute of previous or next parent element child

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is, when i click a child element, to get the attribute of the child of the previous parent element. This is hard to explain so I'll just let my code explain it:

```
$('body').on('click', '.child', function(){
    if($(this).parent().prev().length > 0){
        sid = $(this).parent().prev().children('.child').attr('sid');
        alert(sid);
    }
    else{
        sid = $(this).parent().next().children('.child').attr('sid');
        alert(sid);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nvyy12mz/3/)

It just returns an 'undefined' value. What am I missing?

Comment: Work as expected with the sid attr: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/nvyy12mz/4/

Comment: Is it W3C valid to use a full custom HTML attribute?

Comment: there is no attribute `sid` in the example

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nvyy12mz/5/

Answer (score 1):

None of your elements have an "sid" attribute, so it seems logically, indeed, undefined. What do you try to do ?
Anyway, I do not think "sid" is a valid HTML attribute.

If you want to use a custom attribute, use the "data-*" ones :

```
// HTML DOM
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sid="1">Child1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sid="2">Child2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-sid="3">Child3</div>
</div>

// JS
$('body').on('click', '.child', function() {
    sid = $(this).parent().prev().children('.child').data('sid');
});
```